# Ubuntu boot stuck at "Starting update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes"

Tags: boot, nvidia, 19.04

After some trials of installing the Nvidia video driver  my Ubuntu version 19.04 is blocked at boot on "Starting update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes"

Any ideas about how to solve it? I have tried everything!

Comment: In some cases, after rebooting, it got stuck at "Starting Samba SMB Daemon"

Comment: I removed the "solved" stuff. If you have a solution, post it as an answer.